# MYSQL Connector/J insert and get generated autoincrement key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can insert into MySQL via Connector/J. But:

```
res = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

returns nothing. How do I know the new generated row auto increment key value.
I need to have reference to row I just generated.

Comment: Elaborate your question?

Comment: ok. I just inserted one field and did not put auto increment field intentionally, because it is auto increment. How to know what is generated after the query ran?

Comment: You need to fire another query. Use the database dependent query to get the last inserted record's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `last_insert_id()` or the the JDBC API to retrieve the generated keys:

```
String query = "insert into ....";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query,  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
int rowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
int newId = -1;
ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) 
{
  newId = rs.getInt(1);
}
rs.close();
pstmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after your insert, on the same connection, issue this SQL query:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

It returns the most recently generated autoincrement value. It's stored on a per-connection basis, so it's reliable even on a busy multiclient database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html

Comment: The standard JDBC way is to use the generated keys facility of the JDBC api. I am not sure why you are linking to an ODBC article in a question on JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

the `executeUpdate` returns the number of affected rows by your query.
to get the latest auto increment id you will need to execute another query.  I have used `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` which should return the latest value

Comment: The standard JDBC way is to use the generated keys facility of the JDBC api